# Pop-up message like Game Center

Tags: ios

I would like to know what this pop-up message, like the Game Center one, is really called?
and how can I do it in Xcode?

This is what I am talking about:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's displayed by the system when the user is authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the link which is what you are looking for.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmrnotificationview

Its easy and simple to use and implement.